# Are there specific batteries for pure sine wave UPSes? Do I need a specific type of UPS battery?

Tags: battery, ups

If the battery of my pure sine wave UPS dies, can I replace it with a common UPS battery, or are there specific types of sine wave UPS batteries?

Comment: The output waveform is the work of the UPS circuitry.  The battery just provides power.  Pure sine wave units don't use special batteries.  You should need a pure sine wave UPS only if the computer  has an Active Power Factor Correction power supply.

Answer (score 3):

Replace with the same chemistry/type of battery (such as lead-acid AGM) and voltage/amp-hour rating (such as 12V 7 Ah.)  In the same physical size if you'd like it to fit in the case, of course.

You don't need any sort of "UPS" battery, much less a "Sine-Wave UPS Battery" - almost anyone who is marketing standard rechargeable batteries under those terms is jacking the price "Way" up.

Their business motto - Part a fool from his money and laugh all the way to the bank.